# Is there a way to automate a client purchasing something from paypal?

Tags: paypal

I'm currently building a program to generate test data with PayPal. I need to generate purchases using express checkout. I'm able to automate the creation of a purchase with set express checkout, but I was wondering if there was some API call to have a buyer purchase that specific purchase. For example, is there a way to automate going into https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token= and confirming that purchase? Thanks.

EDIT:
For more clarification, I'm talking about automating step 3 in this link
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/web/web-checkout/

Answer (score 0):

I use nopCommerce as my selling platform. They have a prebuilt PayPal Express module. Have you considered using a pre-built e-commerce solution?

http://www.nopcommerce.com/p/1149/paypal-express-payment-plugin.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In PayPal, it looks like there is no API to finish such website operation, but you can try some testing tools to do this part repeatedly, such as QuickTest Professional.

Answer (score 0):

How about selenium to do the work for you. That's how we test our SDK integration too. Use any testing framework supporting selenium and you should be fine.